# Filter joined results

Tags: mysql, database

Imagine the following table structure:

```
tb.user     tb.usergroups   tb.group
id          id              id
name        user_id         name
            group_id
```

A `user` can be in multiple groups through the `usergroups` table.

I want to search for a user by user name and group name. Speaking in examples: user "Bob" is in "GroupA" and in "GroupB". My query so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
JOIN usergroups ug ON ug.user_id = u.id
JOIN group g ON ug.group_id = g.id
WHERE u.name = 'Bob' AND g.name != 'GroupA'
```

This isn't exactly what I want; my result still contains Bob, since he's in "GroupB", but I don't want the result to contain Bob at all.

How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to select all users named "Bob" that are not in group A but are in group B. This should do it :

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM user u
JOIN usergroups ug ON ug.user_id = u.id
JOIN group g ON ug.group_id = g.id
WHERE u.name = 'Bob' AND g.name = 'GroupB') b
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT userid FROM user u
JOIN usergroups ug ON ug.user_id = u.id
JOIN group g ON ug.group_id = g.id
WHERE u.name = 'Bob' AND g.name = 'GroupA') a
ON a.userid=b.userid
WHERE a.userid is NULL
```

Comment: I guess im not very good in describing my problem... If you search for "not in GroupA" i don't want any Bob in my result, even if he's in GroupB.

Comment: you want to get the group names of all users that are not named Bob ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this query as i understand you are looking something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN usergroups AS ug ON u.id = ug.user_id
LEFT JOIN groups AS gp ON gp.id = ug.group_id
WHERE u.name = 'Bob'
GROUP by ug.user_id
HAVING count(ug.group_id) = 1 AND gp.name !="GROUPA"
```